# React Alice Carousel Property 'stopOnHover' does not exist on type

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm getting the following error while using stopOnHover property of the AliceCarousel which is library of react js. Here is what I have:

```
        <AliceCarousel
                responsive={responsive}
                autoPlayInterval={1500}
                animationDuration={1000}
                autoPlay={true}
                infinite={true}
                disableDotsControls
                disableButtonsControls
                stopOnHover={false}
         >
        </AliceCarousel>
```

Here is the error:

```
C:/Users/sudip/Desktop/rms/rms-frontend/src/Components/HomePage.tsx
TypeScript error in C:/Users/sudip/Desktop/rms/rms-frontend/src/Components/HomePage.tsx(251,9):
Type '{ children: Element[]; responsive: { 0: { items: number; }; 1024: { items: number; }; }; autoPlayInterval: number; animationDuration: number; autoPlay: true; infinite: true; disableDotsControls: true; disableButtonsControls: true; stopOnHover: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<AliceCarousel> & Pick<Readonly<Props> & Readonly<...>, "preservePosition" | ... 5 more ... | "renderPlayPauseButton"> & Partial<...> & Partial<...>'.
      Property 'stopOnHover' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<AliceCarousel> & Pick<Readonly<Props> & Readonly<...>, "preservePosition" | ... 5 more ... | "renderPlayPauseButton"> & Partial<...> & Partial<...>'.  TS2322
    
        249 |         disableDotsControls
        250 |         disableButtonsControls
      > 251 |         stopOnHover={false}
            |         ^
        252 |       >
        253 |         <img
        254 |           src="https://fastly.4sqi.net/img/general/600x600/26654111_cjpS1iqLeaUOyAKJ2AAXByS5vtbMq7B5DPaSMz3utF4.jpg"
```